# Printf is not a part of c language. What actually happens when following PRINTF's code is executed from stdio.h?

Tags: c, printf, stdio

```
int printf (const char *__format, ...)
{
  register int __retval;
  __builtin_va_list __local_argv; __builtin_va_start( __local_argv, __format );
  __retval = __mingw_vprintf( __format, __local_argv );
  __builtin_va_end( __local_argv );
  return __retval;
}
```

above lines are part of `stdio` library corresponding to `printf` function. when `printf` is called these are executed. What do these line mean? what happens when each of the above lines are executed?

Comment: Most of them can be answered by reading about variadic functions.

Comment: If you're interested in seeing how `printf()` can be implemented, an implementation I wrote recently can be seen at: https://github.com/duskwuff/lm-project0/blob/master/stdio.c

Comment: Welcome to SO. You are mistaken, `printf` *is* part of the C language. It is specified as an integral part of C in the standards document. How platforms implement the library part of the language is completely up to them. Usually these implementations are kind of tricky and not so easy to read. If you are a beginner in C, you should probably start reading and writing C programs with simpler code.

Comment: @JensGustedt `printf()` is not part of the C language, it's part of the C standard library, which has a very close relation to the C language. Parts of the C language are declarations, operators, expressions, statements, pointer arithmetic, etc. One could, in theory, write a C compiler without implementing `printf()` (I'm not saying that's useful, but still).

Comment: @H2CO3, the library is part of the language as well as the other parts that you are listing. There are parts of the specification (library and other parts) that *must* be provided by any implementation, and others are optional. The point that I wanted to make is that an implementation of `printf` if written itself in C will necessarily rely on implementation specific things.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is mostly a wrapper for another function `__mingw_vprintf` which does the real work. The only code here is repackaging the variable-argument list. So to really see how Mingw does it, you'll have to look at that function and any other functions it calls. If you're really interested in this, you should get a copy of P.J. Plauger's *The Standard C Library*. He tells you how to use, write, and test every function in the standard library.

Library code in general is compiled into object files (just like your code is), and then packaged in an archive format. When your program is linked, the library objects needed are extracted from the archive and written into the same executable. This is for a *statically-linked* library.

For a dynamically-linked library, the library code archive is loaded as a whole into memory (and usually shared by any programs which need to use it), and your program makes library-calls with the help of the operating system to facilitate the memory-sharing.

For both types of libraries, the header files should only contain macros, types, and function prototypes. It should not contain any function definitions (those belong in `.c` files).

Here's an ancient version of `printf` from before the existence of the standard library: [link](http://minnie.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=V6/usr/source/iolib/printf.c) (<-- This one's actually readable(ish)). Curiously, the [7th-edition](http://minnie.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=V7/usr/src/libc/stdio/printf.c) version looks a lot like the one you quote above:

```
#include    <stdio.h>

printf(fmt, args)
char *fmt;
{
    _doprnt(fmt, &args, stdout);
    return(ferror(stdout)? EOF: 0);
}
```

In this case, `_doprnt` is implemented in assembly language.